# Created Standard Token, deployed successfully but on Myetherwallet error

Tags: truffle, ropsten, infura, openzeppelin

Here is the token contract I created - https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x2cccce414fcdf028c0574766af4302a4abeb5788 
Address: 0x2CCcCe414FCdF028C0574766Af4302A4aBEB5788

For some reason I can not see its total supply or any other info on etherscan, and also when I add a new token on Myetherwallet it gives an error - (error_21) Not a valid ERC-20 token.

What could be the reason? Please help the noob.

I used openzeppelin/truffle/infura, pretty simple contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

import "openzeppelin-solidity/contracts/token/ERC20/StandardToken.sol";

contract TestToken is StandardToken {

string public name = "Token";
string public symbol = "T1";
uint8 public decimals = 18;
uint public INITIAL_SUPPLY = 4000000000000000000000000000;

constructor() public {
  totalSupply_ = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
  balances[msg.sender] = INITIAL_SUPPLY;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`0x2CCcCe414FCdF028C0574766Af4302A4aBEB5788` seems to be your truffle migration contract address.

The actual token is at `0x0f26c1c05f1bbBC7Eff0488F1a98619e8a9758cf`.

Comment: oh yeah, but still https://ropsten.etherscan.io/address/0x0f26c1c05f1bbBC7Eff0488F1a98619e8a9758cf I can't see any Supply amount, holders, symbol and token name.

Comment: so I am quite confused, I see other people's tokens on ropsten network they got those info, even though I also specified them in the source code.

Comment: Verify your contract source, etherscan needs to know the abi before it can start showing stuff. Alternatively, make a transfer from the owner to itself for the total supply. Once etherscan sees a transfer event, they will assume it's an ERC20 token